# Setting multiple fields of an object with different methods

Tags: java, immutability

I have an object which have multiple fields which are a response of several calculations. In order to mekt it I have created a Calculator interface and wrote several Child classes. So each of the calculators will be responsible about setting one field.

```
SampleResponse {
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
}

interface Calculator {
    void calculateAndSet(Sample Response item, Map otherParams);
}

ACalculator implements Calculator {
    void calculateAndSet(SampleResponse item, Map otherParams) {
        int val = ......
        item.setA(val);
    }
}

class SampleService {

    List<Calculators> calcs

   void apply() {
        ....
        SampleResponse sampleResponse = new SampleResponse();
        calcs.foreach(calc -> calc.calculateAndSet(sampleResponse, otherParamsMap));

   }

}
    ...
```

But as you can see, the SampleResponse object is not immutable. Is there a better way to make this fields set like that? what do you think?

Or is my way is ok too?

Answer (score 0):

Two options for immutability in your case:

1. You can use a `Builder` and while it will be mutable, once built the `SampleResponse` will be immutable.
2. Instead of modifying the existing instance and returning `void`, you can create a new instance and return that one. This will make each object immutable, but you'll have to change your variable to point to the returned object.

Comment: 1- BUilder is the one for building custom objects but you say probably "dont use foreach , call all calcs one by one". is it?

Comment: 2- if I return object each time, I need to merge all results in the end I guess. Or do you offer to create new instance of the input SampleResponse and clone it to a new one and return it every time?

Comment: 1 - yes, you'd need to pass the builder to each calc, and only after they all modify it then call `build`.

Comment: 2 - exactly, create the new instance based on the previous one, with some values modified by the calculator.

Comment: then the builder is not immutable :)

Comment: Indeed, as I mentioned in the answer. Generally, I don't think it's a problem.

Comment: 2- the solution makes me feel like that I am cheating to be honest. I mean I m cloning just to make it seem like immutable. I dont know. does not sound elegant

Comment: I think it is quite common, especially in other more functional languages.